# In R, how do I create reciprocal tables showing common variables?

Tags: r, summary

I have a data frame for crop variety trials that shows the presence or absence of varieties in any given location and year. The following example is a subset of the data.

```
example<-structure(list(Variety = 1:88, Site1_Yr1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
Site2_Yr1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L
), 
Site3_Yr1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Site1_Yr2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
Site2_Yr2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), 
Site3_Yr2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), 
.Names = c("Variety", "Site1_Yr1", "Site2_Yr1", "Site3_Yr1", "Site1_Yr2",   "Site2_Yr2", "Site3_Yr2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -88L))
```

I want to summarize the data frame to produce a reciprocal table that shows how many varieties were in common between the combinations of locations and years. The summarized data would look similar to the following. It would also be useful to show the number of varieties that are NOT the same, and the percentage of common varieties.

```
result <- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L), 
.Label = c("Site1_Yr1", 
"Site1_Yr2", "Site2_Yr1", "Site2_Yr2", "Site3_Yr1", "Site3_Yr2"),
class = "factor"), Site1_Yr1 = c(5L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L),
Site2_Yr1 = c(4L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L),
Site3_Yr1 = c(0L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 0L, 1L),
Site1_Yr2 = c(2L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 1L),
Site2_Yr2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 1L), 
Site3_Yr2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L)),
.Names = c("X", "Site1_Yr1", "Site2_Yr1", "Site3_Yr1", "Site1_Yr2", "Site2_Yr2", "Site3_Yr2"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** I applied a version of the script, kindly provided by lmo, to an actual data set.

```
example2<- structure(list(Davis.1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Davis.2 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,   
0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Davis.3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), DREC.1 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), DREC.2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), DREC.3 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), KARE1.1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), KARE1.2 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), KARE1.3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), KARE2.1 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), KARE2.2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), KARE2.3 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), WSREC.1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), WSREC.2 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,   
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), WSREC.3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Davis.1", 
"Davis.2", "Davis.3", "DREC.1", "DREC.2", "DREC.3", "KARE1.1", 
"KARE1.2", "KARE1.3", "KARE2.1", "KARE2.2", "KARE2.3", "WSREC.1", 
"WSREC.2", "WSREC.3"), row.names = c("83G19", "84G62", "85G01", 
"85G03", "86G32", "87P06", "AG1201", "AG1401", "AG2101", "AG2103", 
"AG3101", "DK28E", "DKS-51-01", "DKS-551-0", "DKS-551-01", "DKS-553-6", 
"DKS-553-67", "DKS26-60", "DKS28-05", "DKS37-07", "DKS44-20", 
"DKS51-01", "DKS53-67", "ExP28133", "EXP28133", "KS310", "KS585", 
"NK5418", "NK7829", "NK8416", "R-0413", "R-06173", "R-10413", 
"R-49473", "R-68653", "R-92123", "SP3425"), class = "data.frame")
```

To get names of site-year pairs:

```
sitePairs <- t(combn(1:15, 2, FUN=function(i) names(example2[,i])))
```

To count the same varieties:

```
varietyCount <- combn(1:15, 2, FUN=function(i) sum((rowSums(example2[,i])==2)))
```

This returns all zeros, when there are in fact over 80% matching values in most cases. Clearly I misunderstand what the script is doing???

Comment: Let's see your attempts.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to preserve the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution using `combn`:

```
# get names of site-year pairs
 sitePairs <- t(combn(2:7, 2, FUN=function(i) names(example[,i])))

# count the same varieties
varietyCount <- combn(2:7, 2, FUN=function(i) sum((rowSums(example[,i])==2)))

# put in a data.frame
data.frame("site1"= sitePairs[,1], "site2"= sitePairs[,2], "varietyCount"= varietyCount,
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The `comb` function here produces all pairwise comparisons. I use it first to get the site names. In the calculation, the pairwise combinations from `combn` are fed to a function that uses these pairs to subset the data to the correct columns and then checks if both site-years are producing the varieties (using `RowSums(...) == 2`). This logical vector is then coerced to 1s and 0s and summed.

Since example2 is composed of zeros and 3s, just change `RowSums(...) == 2` to `RowSums(...) == 6` and you will get the counts you are looking for.

Comment: Many thanks! I used your example but had trouble (please see the update above).

Comment: @NicGeorge As I explained in my answer, I used `RowSums(...) == 2` to trigger whether or not the site-year combos produced the same type. Your example dataset was composed of zeros and ones {0, 1}. However, the new dataset is composed of zeros and 3s, so changing this condition to `RowSums(...) == 6` will solve your problem.